# How can i create a conditional check in laravel query

Tags: laravel, query-builder

hi how can we implement a condition checks in laravel query builder

```
$flag_email =true;    
$query = DB::table('customer');

if($flag_email) {
    $query->where('email','=',$email);
}

if(!$flag_email) {
    $query->where('mobile','=',$email);     
}

$query->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

use `when` method here to check condition  [see](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses)

```
$query = DB::table('customer')
->when($flag_email, function ($query,$email) {
      return $query->where('email', $email);
})
->when(!$flag_email, function ($query,$email) {
      return $query->where('mobile', $email);
})->get();
```

Comment: I think we don't want the first semi colon,  however i didn't get the email value in the binding while debugging. so i have to change the above code to

Comment: $users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('otp', '=', $otp)
                ->when($email, function ($users, $email) {
                    return $users->where('email', $email);
                })
                ->when($mobile, function ($users, $mobile) {
                    return $users->where('mobile', $mobile);
                })

Comment: with $flag_email we are  not getting binding values of email and mobile

Comment: ->when($flag_email, function ($query,$email) {
      return $query->where('email', $email);
})  this is correct no need of comma

Answer (score 2):

you can use `->when` to do conditional check

```
$query = DB::table('customer')
->when($flag_email, function ($query, $email) {
      return $query->where('email', $email);
})
->when(!$flag_email, function ($query, $email) {
      return $query->where('mobile', $email);
})->get();
```

Comment: Hey, buddy, this is a syntax error,
this should be like this

```
$query = DB::table('customer')
->when($flag_email, function ($query,$email) {
      return $query->where('email', $email);
}, function ($query) {
      return $query->where('mobile', $email);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator to the rescue:

```
$query = DB::table('customer')->where($flag_email?'email':'mobile',$email);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try by this way. This way will outputs your desire one. This just a way, I am not sure, this one is the proper way.

```
$flag_email =true;    
$query = DB::table('customer');  

if($flag_email)
$query = $query->where('email','=',$email);  

if(!$flag_email)
$query = $query->where('mobile','=',$email);   

$result= $query->get();
```